# getting error "recompile with -fPIC"

Tags: makefile, centos, asterisk, recompile, fpic

After ./configure asterisk in centos I type make command but getting the following error

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/liblua.a(lapi.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `luaO_nilobject_' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/liblua.a: could not read symbols: Bad value

Comment: Try `./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC; make` instead.

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: still not having enough context

Comment: I tried this ./configure CFLAGS=-fPIC but getting same error as above

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the problem. I was compiling on 64 bit platform, but
/usr/local/lib/liblua.a is 32 bit. so I just disable it make menuselect.

Comment: can you describe how to disable it? because I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

your problem seems to be the lua library. if you're on centos, try

```
yum install lua lua-devel
```

and then rerun your `./configure` on asterisk.